# JsonArray converting Array into StringArray

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I created the following String

> [{"lat":"24.8809436","lng":"67.0638776","timeStamp":1527155905396}]

Now i am converting this String to a JsonArray.

```
 jsonArray = new JsonArray();
 jsonArray.add(stringArray)
```

After this line it converts the above mentioned String Array into this format.

> ["[{\"lat\":\"24.8809436\",\"lng\":\"67.0638776\",\"timeStamp\":1527155905396}]"]

This was working fine when i was using `JSONArray`, but since now i am now using retrofit, I switched over to `JsonObject` and `JsonArray`.

**EDIT**

```
    stringArray ="[{"lat":"24.8809436","lng":"67.0638776","timeStamp":1527155905396}]";
    jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    jsonArray.add(stringArray);

    JsonObject jsonobject= new JsonObject();
    jsonobject.add("trail", jsonArray);
```

Comment: share your full code so can help you

Comment: see `JsonArray(String)` constructor

Comment: @pskink jsonArray is not accepting string argument in its constructor

Comment: but i am using JsonArray not JSONArray

Comment: whats the full class name of that `JsonArray`?

Comment: @pskink com.google.gson.JsonArray

Comment: see `com.google.gson.JsonParser` then

Comment: Create a POJO class for your output string and retrofit ConverterFactory automatically map this string into POJO class object.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question, you want to convert the string:
[{"lat":"24.8809436","lng":"67.0638776","timeStamp":1527155905396}]
into a JSON Array.

You should call:

```
jsonArray = new JSONArray(stringArray);
```

This will create a new JSON array from the string if it is correctly formatted JSON to begin with.

Comment: jsonArray is not accepting string argument in its constructor

Comment: I now realize you have moved to retrofit. Sorry about that. I'm more of a Volley person. I hope you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

don't put manually use this code as reference.

```
     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("lat", "24.8809436");
        jsonObject.put("lng", "67.0638776");
        jsonObject.put("timeStamp", "1527155905396");
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
```

this is quite simple and standard code format.